# Python: Creating each item in a list as a variable and assigning a value to it in a for loop

Tags: python

In the below code I would like each item in the list to be created as a variable and then assigned a 'yes' or 'no' value. The loop should goes through each condiment succesfully, but keeps assigning a 'yes' or 'no' value, to 'i', rather than an item in the list, 'mayo' for example. I thought perhaps having str(i) = pyip.inputYesNo(prompt + i +'?') but that doesn't seem to work either. How would I go about rectifying this?

Thanks

```
import pyinputplus as pyip

prompt = 'Do you want '

condiments = ['mayo', 'mustard', 'lettuce', 'tomato']

for i in condiments:
    i = pyip.inputYesNo(prompt + i +'?')
```

Comment: can you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple way you can go about that, my favorite would be the use of a dictionnary.

```py
condiment_love = {}

for i in condiment:
  condiment_love[i] = pyip.inputYesNo(f'do you love {i}?')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use locals() to create the variable.

Try the following example to see how it works.

```
condiments = ['mayo', 'mustard', 'lettuce', 'tomato']

mylocals = locals()
for condiment in condiments:
    mylocals[condiment] = input("Y or N: ")
    
print("mustard:", mustard)
print("locals:", locals())
```

Output:

```
Y or N: n
Y or N: y
Y or N: n
Y or N: n
mustard: y
locals: {'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'condiments': ['mayo', 'mustard', 'lettuce', 'tomato'], 'mylocals': {...}, 'condiment': 'tomato', 'mayo': 'n', 'mustard': 'y', 'lettuce': 'n', 'tomato': 'n'}
```

Source: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/convert-string-to-variable-name-in-python

Comment: uh, no, this is not a very good idea, there are far better approaches than this, like using a dictionary (that you create yourself)

Comment: I agree. But this directly answers the question of this post, rather than offering alternative approach to the problem through data structures.